# Positioning of blocks - product view

Tags: product, layout, catalog, blocks

Let's say that a product view/page has the following blocks,

- product name
- SKU
- stock status
- tabbed content (video, specifications, reviews etc.,)

If a 3rd party module appends its block to the product view then, is there a way to display it within an existing block?

For instance, if a 3rd party module appends product reviews to the product view then, can this block be displayed within the existing 'reviews' block?

I understand that `before` and `after` attributes can be used to position blocks in layouts but, I am looking for something on the lines of `within`.

(display the block from the 3rd party module within an existing block on the product view template)

Any guidance regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly you want the following.
Let's say you have a third part app that has the following XML tag to display it's template

```
<block type="3thparty/reviews" name="3thpart_reviews" template="3thparty/reviews.phtml"/>
```

Now you want to add this to the review view in the product view page.
When you go to the file `base/default/layout/review.xml` you can see on line 96 a block with the name `product.info.product_additional_data`. Via the `local.xml` layout file in your template we'll add the 3thparty review app here.

Add the following code in your templates `local.xml`

```
[...]
<review_product_list translate="label">
    <reference name="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <block type="3thparty/reviews" name="3thpart_reviews" template="3thparty/reviews.phtml"/>
    </block>
</review_product_list>
[...]
```

All you need to do now is echo it in the `review/product/view/list.phtml` template file that you're referencing.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('3thparty_review');?>
```